# Spring Boot + PostgreSQL array invalid query

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.`

when I call `itemreposetory.findByName("test")`

My itemModel class looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_table")
public class ItemModel {
  ...... other parameters

  @Type(LongArrayType.class)
  @Column(
      name = "price",
      columnDefinition = "bigint[]"
  )
  private Long[] price;

  public ItemModel(String name, String description, String category, String[] location, Long[] price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.category = category;
    this.location = location;
    this.price = price;
  }
  ...... other parameters


  public Long[] getPrice() {
    return this.price;
  }

  public void setPrice(Long[] price) {
    this.price = price;
  }
}
```

I expect this to just return the item with the name test and if I check the database manually, it shows up.

When I comment out the setter and getter methods it works, but the prices are no longer put into the database.